# Replacing conditionals with polymorphism in java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have recently started practicing and learning java on my own, I'm having trouble understanding how I can use polymorphism for a better coding practice. how can I use polymorphism refactoring to get rid of if and else conditions in the following code?

I have a parent class Fruit, that has child classes kiwi and apple and bunch of other fruits.
for ex: apple is sweet and kiwi is sour.

I have a parent class Human, that has child classes boy and girl.
boy likes sweet flavor and girl likes sour.
I created an array of fruit objects, and used if statement to check who likes each fruit based on its flavor.

```
Fruit[] fruit = new Fruit[2];
fruit[0] = new Apple ();
fruit[1] = new Kiwi ();
Boy boy1 = new Boy ();
String boyTaste = boy1.taste;
for (int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++){
    if (fruit[i].flavor.equals (boyTaste)){
        System.out.println ("Boy likes " + fruit[i].name + " because " + fruit[i].taste ());
    } else {
        System.out.println ("Girl likes " + fruit[i].name +  " because " + fruit[i].taste ());
    }
}
```

how can I improve this following code by replacing conditions with polymorphism?

Comment: Before "improving" anything, you first have to *fix* that code. flavor appears to be a String, and `if (fruit[i].flavor == boyTaste) {` will often fail.  You shouldn't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: ok thank you for the tip.

Comment: Polymorphism will probably come in very handy if/when you get to implementing both sweet "red" apples and sour "green" apples.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's write a function to check if someone likes a fruit

```java
public boolean likesThisFruit(Human human, Fruit fruit) {}
```

You want to check if `human` likes `fruit`

```java
if ( (human instanceof Boy && fruit.taste.equals("sweet"))
    || (human instanceof Girl && fruit.taste.equals("sour"))
) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

which is equivalent to

```java
return (human instanceof Boy && fruit.taste.equals("sweet")) 
    || (human instanceof Girl && fruit.taste.equals("sour"));
```

Note that you can use `instanceof` to check if an object is an instance of a given type.
Your final function

```java
public boolean likesThisFruit(Human human, Fruit fruit) {
    return (human instanceof Boy && fruit.taste.equals("sweet")) 
        || (human instanceof Girl && fruit.taste.equals("sour"));
}
```

I recommend you to use `Interfaces` : Sour & Sweet. And use `instanceof` in your function.
Such as

```java
public boolean likesThisFruit(Human human, Fruit fruit) {
    return (human instanceof Boy && fruit instanceof Sweet) 
        || (human instanceof Girl && fruit instanceof Sour);
}
```

and with

```java
public class Apple extends Fruit implements Sweet {}
```

**EDIT TO MATCH OP REQUEST**

```java
interface Taste {}
interface Sour extends Taste {}
interface Sweet extends Taste {}
```

```java
public abstract class Human {
    protected final Class taste;
    Human(Class taste) {
        this.taste = taste;
    }
    public boolean likes(Fruit fruit) {
        return fruit instanceof taste;
    } 
}

public class Boy extends Human {
    Boy(Class taste) {
        super(taste);
    }
}
```

I suppose here that Fruit implements Sour or Sweet interface

```java
Boy boy = new Boy(Sweet.class);
boy.likes(new Apple()); //true
boy.likes(new Kiwi()); //false if Kiwi implements Sour
```

When assigning the taste you should check through a setter whether the Class passed is a Taste or not (with instanceof).

Comment: Then your function ```likesFruit``` should be inside Human class and be overriden in child class. Each Human have a Taste (Sour or Sweet), the taste is a class passed in parameter. You then check if the fruit is instanceof yourTaste. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you share the complete code please, I've been trying your directions but still getting errors.@IQbrod

Answer (score 0):

First things first, **never** use `==` to compare `String`s. Always use `.equals()`, e.g. `str.equals("hello")`.

It's not clear what you could improve using specifically polymorphism/inheritance. An argument could be made that `Boy boy1 = new Boy();` should be replaced with `Human boy1 = new Boy();`, but in this case, since it is a local variable that is only used once, and is instantiated in the method, it doesn't make a huge amount of difference.

A thing you may want to do is create methods on `Human` called `likesFruit()` and `getMessage()` like follows:

```
public abstract class Human {

    ...

    public boolean likesFruit(Fruit f) {
        return f.getFlavor().equals(getTaste());
    }

    public abstract String getMessage();

    ...
}
```

`getMessage()` would be defined in `Boy` as:

```
public String getMessage() {
    return "Boy likes %s because ...";  // truncated for brevity
}
```

and a similar implementation for `Girl`.

Then in your code, you can call:

```
Human human = new Boy();
Fruit[] fruits = ...

for (Fruit fruit : fruits) {
    if (human.likesFruit(fruit)) System.out.println(String.format(human.getMessage(), fruit.getName(), fruit.getFlavor()));
}
```

A few things to note:

- I have replaced field references with getters/setters (e.g. `fruit.flavor` becomes `fruit.getFlavor()`. This is good practice as it hides the necessary state from the caller, and allows you to perform logic when the getter is called.
- `Human` is `abstract`. It is impossible to have a `Human` who is not also a `Boy` or a `Girl` (or `Man`/`Woman` etc, politics aside), and so should be illegal to instantiate a plain `Human`.
- Similarly, `getMessage()` is abstract, since the implementation changes based on the subclass

Comment: Thank you for the tips but is there a way not to use IF statement??

Comment: Why do you want to remove the `if` statement? This case works for any `Human` and and `Fruit`. Long chained `if` statements are bad if they hardcode implementation-specifics, but this does not do that. Any way to forcibly remove `if` statements would leave your code less readable, for not much apparent gain.

Answer (score 0):

After you fix the comparisons, in order to introduce polymorphism, you need to move the "conditions" from your main() method into the class definitions. At some level though, you can't get away from using if/else.  But the for-loop in your "polymorphic" main method might look something like this:

```
Human person = new Boy(FlavorPreferences.SWEET)
for (int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) { 
    System.out.println(person.likes(fruit[i]);
}
```

Also - Just because the boy doesn't like a given "fruit", doesn't necessarily mean the girl likes that same fruit.  Maybe some boys and girls have the same tastes in fruit flavors.

Comment: Comment: It's unclear for user where polymorphism here, because no implementation of likes is provided. Your solution works for an overrided function but none is shown and may confuse OP

Comment: Since OP is learning, I've left some details out to assist the learning process.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the code in the following manner:

- if possible use enum for flavors - will help you avoid a lot of coding mistakes.
- replace the find method with a more modern approach, maybe using streams API (if Java version allows)
- split the code into functionally well rounded methods, and distribute them across classes 
  in a meaningful manner

To that point here's how I'd write it:

I'd create a fruit class like this, and add flavor enum as a subclass (as flavor is a property of fruit)

```
public class Fruit {
private FLAVOR flavor;

public Fruit( FLAVOR flavor ) {
    this.flavor = flavor;
}

public FLAVOR getFlavor() {
    return this.flavor;
}

public static enum FLAVOR {
    SWEET, 
    SOUR;
}
```

}

The human class would look something like this

```
public class Human {
private FLAVOR flavor;
public Human( FLAVOR flavor ) {
    this.flavor = flavor;
}

public List<Fruit> findLikedFruit( List<Fruit> availableFruits ) {
    List<Fruit> likes = availableFruits.stream().filter( candidate -> Human.this.flavor == candidate.getFlavor() ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
    return likes;
}
```

}

it basically contains the liked flavor, and a method which consumes the list of available fruits and returns a list containing only those liked

finally both fruit and human would be extended like this (example only on Fruit, but the principle applies)

```
public static class Apple extends Fruit {
    public Apple() {
        super(FLAVOR.SOUR);
    }
}
```

the main class would look something like this:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    List<Fruit> fruits = Arrays.asList( new Fruit[] {new Apple(), new Pear(), new Strawberry()});
    List<Fruit> boyLikes = new Boy().findLikedFruit(  fruits );
    //if you wanna output it, you could do like so
    boyLikes.forEach(fruit -> System.out.println( fruit.getFlavor().name() ) );
}
```

This makes the code way more safe, much more expandable in the future, and complies to modern java coding practices.

Hope that helps

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Where you are running into trouble is that you are trying to use polymorphism for something that is a simple property -- the taste of the fruit.   Polymorphism is for different behavior, not just different values.  I tried to come up with an example with fruit, but failed.

Consider, instead, bank accounts.  Assume there is an abstract concept of a bank account that defines the interface, including a method withdrawMoney(double amount).

```
interface Account {  
  boolean withdrawMoney(double amount);
}

class SimpleAccount implements Account {
  double cash;   // Assume initialized in constructor, not shown.
  boolean withdrawMoney(double amount) {
    if (amount <= cash) {
      cash -= amount;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
class OverdraftProtectedAccount implements Account {
  double cash;
  Account overdraftAccount;  // Assume both initialized in constructor
  boolean withdrawMoney(double amount) {
    if (amount <= cash) {
       cash -= amount;
       return true;
    } else if (overdraftAccount.withdrawMoney(amount - cash)) {
       cash = 0;
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
  }
}
```

This example has, of course, lots of problems with timing, and with just returning a boolean, but the point is to show the idea that polymorphism is about behavior, not data.